# Is there a way to edit a note / card in a new window using the anki card browser? (add-In?)

Tags: anki

I am wondering if there is a possibility to implement editing an Anki note in a new window (similar to the Card creation dialogue) once the note / card is created and located using the card browser.

The reason I want to do this is that screen space is often limited and it would be useful to have more space for creating elaborate (10Q/10A) notes using a separate window (similar to the one appearing when pressing 'e' during review).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you go](https://github.com/Glutanimate/anki-addons-misc/blob/master/anki-browser-external-editor.py), I've written a small add-on for this. It was simply a matter of reimplementing the `EditCurrent` window and performing one or two adjustments to existing methods in the card browser.

You can invoke the editor on a selected note with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

For now you'll have to manually install the add-on, but I'll see if I can post it on AnkiWeb later.

Let me know if you run into any issues. Viel Spaß damit!

Comment: Works great, thank you so much for your help! I'll try to learn from your implementation as well so that I can contribute other minor improvements.